# Laravel: server.php se elimina solo cuando arranco el servidor

Tags: laravel

Hola necesito de ayuda urgente tengo un proyecto que cada vez que arraco el sistema el server.php ser borra y luego me sale este error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego cuando intento copiar el archivo a la misma ruta me sale que no tengo permisos, tengo que reiniciar el ordenador para volver a copiarlo, arranco el sistema con PHP ARTISAN SERVE y nuevamente se vuelve a borrar. No se que sucede por favor su ayuda.

Comment: que versión de php tienes instalada? y que versión de php usas?

Comment: Tengo la 5.6 no encuentro solución en ningún lado para este problema. Muchas gracias

Comment: y de php cual usas?

Comment: php 7 uso el XAMPP

Comment: Muchas gracias lo intentare espero que funcione.

Comment: No funciona, se sigue borrando el archivo serve.php

Comment: Cuando te refieres al sistema, te refieres al sistema operativo o directamente a la aplicación en php?

Comment: Me refieron a la Aplicacion Web de Laravel

Comment: es el antivirus que lo envia a la cuarentena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hola me pasaba lo mismo

Solucione creando otro proyecto y copiando el server.php al que estoy trabajando

Luego agregar una excepcion al antivirus, al parecer este lo borra

saludos

Comment: Hola Lucas, por favor, no uses una respuesta para replicar a una pregunta, debes usar la sección de comentarios o formular una nueva pregunta